# "sudo apt-get upgrade" Failure in 'bind9'

Tags: command-line, apt, stable-release-updates

I am running this command in terminal-

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y -f
```

And find this error-

```
Get:1 Changelog for libisc95 (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9_9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.8/changelog) [68.7 kB]
bind9 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.8) trusty-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via rndc control channel input
    parsing error
    - properly check data in bin/named/control.c, bin/named/controlconf.c,
      bin/rndc/rndc.c, lib/isccc/cc.c.
    - CVE-2016-1285
  * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via resource record signatures
    parsing issue
    - fix improper DNAME handling in lib/dns/resolver.c.
    - CVE-2016-1286

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Tue, 08 Mar 2016 08:32:14 -0500

Get:1 Changelog for firefox (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_45.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1/changelog) [458 kB]
firefox (45.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) trusty-security; urgency=medium

  * New upstream stable release (FIREFOX_45_0_BUILD2)
    - see USN-2917-1
:
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The errors log are given here

Comment: SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via rndc control channel input
    parsing error

Comment: That's not an error. That is what the update is fixing.

Comment: Yes, after I have my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it's solution.

It is actually [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) Text Editor showing change-logs.

SO, if I just quit vim using `q` then I am done :)

Comment: The quit-command in vi is `:q`